# NoMethodError: undefined method ascii_only? - Error with mail 2.5.4 and rails 4.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

Please find below error message occured when I tried to deliver mails with mail 2.5.4 / rails 4.0.0 / ruby 1.9.3-p125 configuration.

```
SubscriptionMailer.send_email(Subscription.last).deliver
  Subscription Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `subscriptions`.* FROM `subscriptions` ORDER BY `subscriptions`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered subscription_mailer/send_email.text.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered subscription_mailer/send_email.html.haml (5.7ms)
NoMethodError: undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/encodings.rb:68:in `param_encode'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:95:in `block in stringify'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:95:in `each'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:95:in `map'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:95:in `stringify'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:88:in `value'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:28:in `parse'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/fields/content_type_field.rb:24:in `initialize'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:203:in `new'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:203:in `new_field'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:192:in `create_field'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/field.rb:149:in `update'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/header.rb:170:in `[]='
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:588:in `content_type='
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:695:in `mail'
  from /opt/blog/app/mailers/subscription_mailer.rb:19:in `send_email'
... 8 levels...
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:497:in `initialize'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `new'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:480:in `method_missing'
  from (irb):4
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:43:in `require'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:43:in `block in exec_app_rails'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `loop'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:32:in `exec_app_rails'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/bin/rails:9:in `require'
  from /opt/blog/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:16:in `load'
  from bin/rails:16:in `<main>'1.9.1 :005 >
```

Comment: I suspect somekind of field in the email header of in your email configuration is empty. It would be helpful if you pasted the mailer class and your mailer config.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem that occurred when sending attachments.

I needed to change `attachments[:report]` to `attachments['report']`

old:

`def email_report(email, report)
    attachments[:report] = File.read(report)
    mail(to: email, subject: 'report')
end`

new:

`def email_report(email, report)
    attachments['report'] = File.read(report)
    mail(to: email, subject: 'report')
end`

I suspect something similar is happening to you.

Comment: similar issue here. please help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29441305/cannot-create-firefox-browser-with-watir-webdriver

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue because I had set a User-instance in the 'to'-field instead of the user.email value.

Comment: I had a similar issue, this was due to the address not being the actual email address

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error message when sending activestorage attached files
as mail attachments.  the problem was in the filename:

```
files.each do |file|
  # this next line does not work, throws NoMethodError: undefined method ascii_only?
  filename = file.filename  
  attachments[filename] = {
    mime_type: file.blob.content_type,
    content: file.blob.download
  }
end
```

when I convert the filename to a string explicitly the error went away:

```
files.each do |file|
  # convert to string and it does work!
  filename = file.filename.to_s
  attachments[filename] = {
    mime_type: file.blob.content_type,
    content: file.blob.download
  }
end
```

Comment: Thank you for spending your time to post this, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.
i had the following:

```
include HTTParty
```

and changed it to

```
require 'httparty'
```

and it worked for me.

hope this helps.