# ruby ascii_only error applies to unknown 'nil'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following controller code intends to launch a mailer, with some debugging pointers.

```
puts params[:message]
  @message = params[:message]
puts @consumer.nil?
puts @gifted_consumer.nil?
puts @roleshopuser.nil?
puts @gifted_consumer_transaction.nil?
puts @message.nil?
  GiftMailer.welcome(@consumer, @gifted_consumer, @roleshopuser, @gifted_consumer_transaction, @message).deliver
```

The log returns

```
hallo there this is to thank you 
false
false
false
false
false

GiftMailer#welcome: processed outbound mail in 30.0ms
Skipped delivery of mail  as `perform_deliveries` is false
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 370ms (ActiveRecord: 36.9ms | Allocations: 162271)

NoMethodError (undefined method `ascii_only?' for nil:NilClass):
```

The mailer:

```
def welcome(consumer, gifted_consumer, roleshopuser, gifted_consumer_transaction, message)
  @consumer = consumer
  @user = gifted_consumer
  @roleshopuser = roleshopuser
  @transaction = gifted_consumer_transaction
  @message = message
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: (t('mailergift.title') + ' ' + @roleshopuser.shop.name ) )
end
```

I do not understand why the `ascii_only?`  method kicks in here **nor** what is nil, as the debugging pointers declare `false` for every variable associated to the method.  If the `@message` variable is removed, the mailer processes.

How do I resolve this matter of passing just the message to the mailer (*this is not a saved attribute of any class record*)

Comment: Can you paste the code of your mailer? It is hard to figure out what would be the issue here without that. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997081/nomethoderror-undefined-method-ascii-only-error-with-mail-2-5-4-and-rails-4) Maybe this would help but not sure without `GiftMailer` code.

Comment: question updated.  Yes I had seen that post; not apparently helpful.

Comment: Did you check `@user.email`, is it present?

Comment: Yes, that's not the issue.  As the question indicates, removing the `message` variable from the function, the mailer processes.